# Selecting more than one element at a time in Chrome Developer Tooling?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to select more than one element at a time in the Chrome developer tooling?  I tried `shift` and `ctrl+shift` and `ctrl` but none of these do the trick ...

Comment: Why would you want to inspect more than one element at a time? That in itself sounds like an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: Delete multiple elements at one time.